# How can I store a list of ggplots to use in multiplot without overwriting previous plots?

Tags: arrays, r, list, ggplot2

I want to plot some heatmaps of covariance/correlation matrices in a multiplot using an object created from another function (the `cd` parameter below).  The covariance matrices are stored in an array of 3 dimensions, so that `cd$covmat[,,i]` calls the ith covariance matrix.

Originally I had some issues with this with having the same plot replicated.  However, I discovered I had an environment issue.  I've tried resolving this several ways, with the code below being the most recent, but I can't figure out why it's not reading it properly.

Is there a particular reason for this?  I've tried including and excluding the environment parameter (which I hopefully shouldn't need) and I've tried directly using the `cd$covmat[,,i]` in the 
`aes()` parameter.

```
drawCovs<-function(cd,ncols){
    require(ggplot2)
    coords=expand.grid(x=1:cd$q,y=1:cd$q)
    climits = c(-1,1)*max(cd$covmat)
    cd$levels=c(cd$levels,"Total")
    covtext=ifelse(!(cd$use.cor),'Covariance','Correlation')
    plots=list()
    cmat=list()
    for (i in 1:(nlevels+1)){
        cmat[[i]]<-cd$covmat[,,i]
        .e<-environment
        plots[[i]]<-ggplot(environment=.e)+geom_tile(aes(x=coords$x,y=coords$y,
        fill=as.numeric(cmat[[i]]),color='white'))+
        scale_fill_gradient(covtext,low='darkblue',high='red',limits=climits)+ylab('')
        +xlab('')+guides(color='none')+scale_x_discrete(labels=cd$varnames,
        limits=1:cd$q, expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_discrete(labels=cd$varnames,
        limits=1:cd$q, expand=c(0,0))+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,
        hjust = 1))+labs(title=paste0(covtext,"s of data, ",cd$levels[i]))
    }

    multiplot(plotlist=plots,cols=ncols)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `.e<-environment`? do you have a variable named -"environment"?

Comment: Oh, I meant to use `environment()` instead.  Doesn't resolve the issue, though.

Comment: I haven't said that. You should make a reproducible example...

Comment: Oh, okay.  I updated the code above to include a reproducible example.  Apparently the original issue I had was that ggplot was looking in the global environment, so there were some local changes that it couldn't find.  However, I'm still having issues fixing these local changes.  I've tried doing `.e<-environment()` to capture the local environment, and I've tried evaluating the expression in a specified type of environment using `eval` and `substitute`, but that's not working, either.

Comment: The `multiplot()` function is from the [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you end up trying to fix things with direct calls to environments, you are probably overcomplicating your code. Here's a simple snippet that may serve as a core for your function:

```
drawCovs <- function(cd, ncols) {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  plots=list()
  cmat=list()
  for (i in 1:(length(cd$covmat))) {
    cmat[[i]] <- cd$covmat[[i]]
    plots[[i]] <- ggplot(melt(cmat), aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
                  geom_tile(color='white')
  }  
  multiplot(plotlist=plots,cols=ncols)
}

cd <- list()
cd$covmat <- list(matrix(runif(25), 5), matrix(runif(25), 5))

drawCovs(cd, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I should try using `melt()` more often.  This is definitely a much better way of doing it.  I'm still a bit puzzled at the issues I was having with the environments, though.