# Why does ggplot2 overwrite plots in a list?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

If I want to create a list of ggplot objects, then every new plot overwrites the old plot. It is similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736490/how-can-i-store-a-list-of-ggplots-to-use-in-multiplot-without-overwriting-previo). Though I was able to solve the issue using lapply, but I am still not able to figure out why the plots are getting overwritten inside the loop.

```
library(ggplot2)
trash <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 50, ncol = 2))
colTrash <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 50, ncol = 2))

##Overwritten: both plots are same
pltList <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
  pltList[[i]] <- ggplot(trash)+
    geom_point(aes(X1,X2,color = colTrash[,i]))
}

#Not Overwritten: plots are different and correct
pltList <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
  ggplot(trash)+
    geom_point(aes(X1,X2,color = colTrash[,i]))
})
```

Comment: You encountered lazy evaluation! In the loop only the call to the function is stored, it is not evaluated. Evaluation happens when you try to display the plot. To illustrate this first run your loop and then set `i<-NULL` - now none of the plots can be evaluated!

Comment: So does that mean that in case the case of `lapply` evaluation occurs instantaneously? Also, what is the specific use of lazy evaluation?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235825/for-loop-only-adds-the-final-ggplot-layer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317502/update-a-ggplot-using-a-for-loop-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057189/strange-behaviour-of-ggplot2/39057372#39057372) are a few SO questions that address this issue. Lazy evaluation is discussed [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) in the book Advanced R.

Comment: If you use `force` inside your loop (appropriately) you can force it to evaluate and things will run as you expect.